# ReactJS+Typescript: Why is the State type required in React.Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In this simple component, I pass in MyProps which looks like this:

```
interface MyProps {
    profiles: IProfile[] 
}

interface IProfile {
   name: string;
   avatar_url: string;
   company: string;
}
```

My component defines props as `MyProp`, but the Typescript compiler complains that `this.state.profiles does not exist on type  Readonly<{}>`:

```
class App extends React.Component<MyProps>  {

constructor(props: MyProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { profiles: props.profiles };
}

public render() {
    return (<div>//ERROR HERE
                {this.state.profiles.map((profile: IProfile) => <Card {...profile} />)}  
            </div>);
}

};
```

If I set the second field to any or MyProps it works. Do I always need to define the first 2 params of the React.Component?

```
class App extends React.Component<MyProps,MyProps>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Within TypeScript, `React.Component` is a generic type (aka
>   `React.Component<PropType, StateType>`)

[source](https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react-typescript-cheatsheet#class-components)

Since you are defining state within that component, you will need to create an interface for your state for typechecking.

```
interface MyState {
  profiles: IProfile[];
}
```

After creating that, you can supply that to your React.Component

```
class App extends React.Component<MyProps, MyState>  {

  constructor(props: MyProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { profiles: props.profiles };
  }

  public render() {
    return (<div>//ERROR HERE
      {this.state.profiles.map((profile: IProfile) => <Card {...profile} />)}  
    </div>);
  }

};
```

Comment: Ok, so basically, TS requires that I define both props and state when I use them in the Component.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to expand slightly on the already provided answer.

Until relatively recently you ALWAYS had to supply both the Props type and the State type to the `Component<P,S>` generic type, so `class App extends React.Component<MyProps>` would have been an error, saying you need to supply a type for State.

Now, Typescript supports defaulting generic types, and the React types make use of this by defining:

```
interface Component<P = {}, S = {}, SS = any> extends ComponentLifecycle<P, S, SS> { }
```

This means that you no longer are required to *always* provide types for Props and State, and if you do *not* provide types, they will default to the type `{}`, which is an object with no properties. As the property `profiles` does not exist on the type `{}`, you get the type error you are observing.

I only raise this distinction because the actual answer to your question is no, because of generic type defaulting, you do *not* always need to define the first two params of `React.Component`. But if you do not supply them they will be defaulted to the type `{}`, which has no properties. So, you must supply the Props and State type if you are going to be making use of Props and State inside your component.

Comment: Thank you for further explaining the background, I find it helpful and insightful.